# El nombre "Session" no existe en el contexto actual (WPF)

Tags: wpf, session

Buenas, tengo una aplicación de escritorio que estoy haciendo en WPF en Visual Studio y necesito almacenar la identificacion de un paciente en una variable de Session para poder usarla en otras ventanas de la aplicación pero al intentar crearla obtengo el error "El nombre "Session" no existe en el contexto actual", aquí les dejo parte del codigo, espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias :D

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using BLL;



            if(metodos.buscarPaciente(txtRut.Text) == false)
            {
                //Crear paciente
                PacienteBLL miPaciente = new PacienteBLL();

                miPaciente.nombre = txtNombre.Text;
                miPaciente.apePaterno = txtApePaterno.Text;
                miPaciente.apeMaterno = txtApeMaterno.Text;
                miPaciente.rut = txtRut.Text;
                miPaciente.direccion = txtDireccion.Text;
                miPaciente.viveCon = txtViveCon.Text;
                miPaciente.ocupacion = txtOcupacion.Text;
                miPaciente.fk_idEscolaridad = cbEscolaridad.SelectedIndex;
                miPaciente.edad = int.Parse(txtEdad.Text);
                miPaciente.fk_idPrevision = cbPrevision.SelectedIndex;
                miPaciente.ciudad = txtCiudad.Text;
                miPaciente.fk_idEstCivil = cbEstCivil.SelectedIndex;
                miPaciente.motivoConsulta = txtMotivo.Text;

                Session["rut"] = txtRut.Text;

                miPaciente.Crear();
                MessageBox.Show("Paciente registrado con éxito", "Información", MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                //Ya existe
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Session es en aplicaciones web. Te sugiero usar una clase con propiedades estáticas.

Comment: Si agregaras un ejemplo sencillo tu respuesta estaria completa.

Comment: seria por ejemplo 
public static string rut; (a esta variable le asigno el valor)

pero para llamarla desde la otra ventana del wpf como tendria que hacerlo? Saludos!

Comment: encontre una solucion, al crear la instancia de la ventana hija le paso el valor como parametro así, Antecedentes misAntecedentes = new Antecedentes(txtRut.Text); y lo recibo en la ventana antecedentes, era muy simple, gracias de todos modos!